# What is the difference between before/ after to refer to the past, present, future

Tags: difference

What is the difference between before/ after to refer to the past, present, future.
if there are ones which are common in BrE, say to me.

1(a) I always have breakfast before going to university.
(b) I always have breakfast before I go to university
(c) I always have breakfast before I have gone to university .

2(a) I had breakfast before going to university
OR
(b) I had breakfast before I went to university
OR
(c) I had had breakfast before I went to school

3(a) I always go to university after having breakfast.
(b) I always go to university after I have breakfast.
(c) I always go to university after I have had breakfast.

4(a)I went home after watching GOT.
(b) I went home after I I watched GOT.
(c)I went home after I had watched GOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 (a) and (b) are both idiomatic, but (c) is not.

2(a) and (b) are both idiomatic. (c) could be used if there is a suggestion of eating another breakfast at school.

3 All options are possible, but sound odd (does the speaker really go to university every single day?).

4 (a) and (c) both idiomatic; (b) might be idiomatic to an American (without the repeated *I*).